# Term between "orthogonal" and "orthonormal"

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, multilinear-algebra

If we have a bilinear form $(-, -)$ on a vector space $V$, a basis $\beta$ of $V$ is said to be *orthogonal* if $(v, w) = 0$ for every $v \neq w \in \beta$, and *orthonormal* if moreover $(v, w) = 1$ when $v = w$.

What if we relax the latter condition to $(v, v) \neq 0$ for $v \in \beta$?  Is there a name for that?  I've tried looking in the usual places and Googling but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Somehow this question reminds me of the distinction between the groups ${\rm Sp}(V)$ and ${\rm GSp}(V)$.

Comment: The words "isotropic" and "anisotropic" are relevant but maybe not exactly what you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\K{\mathbb K}
$

To summarize, this is a property of the *form*, and not the basis. If there is one orthogonal basis satisfying this, then all of them do.

---

Your definition of orthogonal basis implies that if such a basis exists then $({-},{-})$ is symmetric, so I will assume out right that it is.

In characteristic 2, $({-},{-})$ need not have a orthogonal basis. We will ignore this case, as it is quite different from when the characteristic is not 2.

When the characteristic is not 2, then $({-},{-})$ always has an orthogonal basis $\beta$. Moreover, the number of basis elements $v \in \beta$ such that $(v,v) \not= 0$ is independent of $\beta$, and is called the *rank* of $({-},{-})$. So a symmetric bilinear form with $(v,v) \not= 0$ for all $v \in \beta$ has *full rank*, or more commonly is *non-degenerate*.

This is distinct from $({-},{-})$ being anisotropic. $({-},{-})$ is *isotropic* if there is $0\not= v \in V$ such that $(v, v) = 0$, and is *anisotropic* otherwise. But consider the form
$$
  ((x, y), (x', y')) = xx' - yy'
$$
over $\mathbb R^2$. $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ is an orthogonal basis for this form, and
$$
  ((1,0), (1, 0)) = 1,\quad ((0,1),(0,1)) = -1
$$
so the form is non-degenerate. But
$$
  ((1,1), (1,1)) = 1 - 1 = 0.
$$
Of course, any degenerate form is isotropic.

---

A good reference is *Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra* (2002) by Larry Grove.

Comment: I see, there's a distinction between "vector with $(v, v) = 0$" and "vector with $(v, v) = 0$ which belongs to at least one orthogonal basis."

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Yes, precisely. The vector $(1,1)$ in my example cannot be extended to an orthogonal basis. This is in stark contrast to the Euclidean case, where every non-zero vector is part of an orthogonal basis.